# What is the conditional density of a variable that is a function of two random variables?

Tags: statistics, measure-theory, density-function

I am confused about the following identities of probability densities $p$ which lead to an apparent contradiction. Assume there are two random variables $X$ and $W$ and $Y=f(X,W)$.

$$p(Y|X) = \int p(Y|X,W)p(W|X)dW$$

$p(Y|X,W)$ is the conditional density, but does it have positive density anywhere? If not, what happens to the integral if we multiply $p(W|X)$ by zero?

Comment: Maybe I am not getting it. The conditional density itself can be zero somewhere but of course not for every $Y$ since it must integrate to one. Was this the problem?

Comment: The integral is $0$  where function is $0$. But elsewhere the integral is not $0$.

Comment: @Thomas But $Y$ is a deterministic function of $X$ and $W$, so given $X$ and $W$, there is no randomness in $Y$; it's value is determined. So what value does the density have then? Assume $X$ and $W$ are normal; then $Y=X+W$ is the convolution and also normal. Now let $X=x_0$, $W=w_0$. So $Y=x_0+w_0$ without randomness. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: @callculus see remark above.

Comment: If Y is deterministic than $p(Y|X,W)=\delta(Y-f(X,W))$ where Delta is the dirac Delta function

Comment: @Thomas This is helpful. So the density is one at the function value $f$ and zero elsewhere?

Comment: Yes... More or less! With the additional property that when you integrate over Y you get one. The point is that you are integrating over W. Try to follow the Wikipedia page on Delta function, section Properties/Composition with a function to expand the integral over w

Comment: So the value is technically infinite at the function value f so it is not really defined asa standard function but as a distribution...

Answer (score 1):

I switch to lower case letters as arguments of the density functions, since upper case letters are usually reserved, in my experience, for the stochastic variables.

As discussed in the comments if Y is a deterministic function of X and W than:

$p(y|x,w)=\delta(y-f(x,w))$

Therefore the integral becomes:

$p(y|x)=\int dw \delta(y-f(x,w)) p(w|x)$

Calling $w_i(x,y)$ the $w$ s.t. $f(x,w_i)=y$ this gets expanded as:

$p(y|x)=\sum_i \frac{p(w_i|x)}{|(\partial_w f)(x,w_i)|}$

I do not know if this can be made more explicit without fixing $f$. I stress the dependence of the $w_i$ on $x,y$ even if to lighten the notation I did not indicate it...